# How do these different types of delcerations of Arrays work exactly?

Tags: java, arrays

So what I know is that you declare an Array the following ways:

```
int[] arr;
```

to initialize it :

```
arr = new int [integer]
```

The statements can also be combined into:

```
int[] arr = new int[integer];
```

Also the combination of declaring, initializing and filling values for the arrays seems clear to me:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 4, 5, 9};
```

However, what puzzles me is that this also works:

```
int[] testAr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

What puzzles me even more is the same principle with multi dimensional arrays:

```
int[][] yarr = new int[][]{ new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{2, 3}, new int[]{3, 4} };
```

Why does this work and what is happening here exactly? Is there ever a reason for me to create an array in the way like the last 2 versions? Also when I think about it why is it okay to leave out the new keyword when filling an array directly with values? 
I've just started to learn about objects and this goes against the basic principles of what I know so far.

Comment: Why does this work? Because that's how the language was defined.

Comment: `new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}` is the most generally usable way of creating and initializing an array. The way without the `new int[]` is just syntactic sugar, but only works at the same time as declaring the variable (e.g. `int[] arr; arr = {1,2,3};` isn't allowed).

Comment: You should read JLS first [Array Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

Comment: Thanks rkosegi I was hoping someone would link me to some further reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};` is a shortcut for the statement `int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3};`.

The statement `int[][] arr = new int[][]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` is a shortcut for the statement `new int[][]{new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{3, 4}}`.

They are absolutely identical, the first ones add some syntax sugar to simplify **array initialisation**. According to the specification:

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration, or as part of an array creation expression, to create an array and provide some initial values.

A compile-time error occurs if an initialiser is used in a different scope. For instance,

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method({1, 2, 3});          // it is not allowed
        method(new int[]{1, 2, 3}); // it is fine
    }

    static void method(int[] ints) { ... }
}
```